# How can I add to Criteria order by condition with to_char function

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have in my Hibernate project a Criteria object and I want to add to it the `order by` condition of a date field

But I want to order by this field with *dd/mm/yyyy* format, and in the database this field is saved in *dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss* format.

In SQL this code looks as follows:

```
order by to_char(date_field_name, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

How can I add this functionality to `Criteria.addOrder`?

In other words how can I write the following?

```
Criteria.addOrder(to_char(date_field_name, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

If I do that I get error: `no field name in the table`

Or maybe someone knows the other solution of this order case?

Comment: If you use string comparison, consider using 'yyyy/mm/dd' because the date fields appear in correct order of significance (left to right). Your method would make '20/01/2012' greater than '19/02/2012'.

Comment: @user845279 ok you right i talk about date format thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your criteria, after adding the parameter that contains the date (let's call it "currentDate") try this (for ascendent order):

```
.addOrder(Order.asc("currentDate"))
```

Comment: my current date in the database in format with hours and minutes but i want that order do this to this field as it in format dd/mm/yyyy i need this to run sub order by title in same dates rows